# Jquery delay function execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

I want execute 2 functions in jquery but i need the second function execute after 3 seconds more or less , i try this , but if use this , the second function of jquery never execute finally , i put the script i create and i try works continue :

```
   jQuery("#tem_forma").hide();
    delay(3000);
    jQuery("#win").hide(1000);
```

How i can use delay function for wait 3 seconds for execute the next function , in this case the second

Thank´s , Regards !!!

Answer (score 13):

Use **setTimeout**

```
jQuery("#tem_forma").hide();
setTimeout( function() {  jQuery("#win").hide(1000); }, 3000);
```

This will make sure your functions gets executed after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.delay()` like this:

```
jQuery("#tem_forma").hide();
jQuery("#win").delay(3000).hide(1000);
```

But be aware that `.hide()`  needs to have (time) parameter to work in conjunction with `.delay()`

Comment: `hide` and `show` with a passed in duration property behaves like effects.. So it will work in such cases. But does not if the parameter is ommitted

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant?

```
jQuery("#tem_forma").hide();
jQuery("#win").delay(3000).hide(1000);
```

Comment: That is because you are passing the duration property.. It does not work without any parametrs

Comment: You are correct but the OP also had params. I was aiming for less code.